# If $\begin{cases} \sin(x)\cos(y)=-\frac{1}{3}\\ \cos(x)\sin(y)=\frac{2}{3},\end{cases}$ find $\cot(x-y)$

Tags: trigonometry

I rewrote $\cot(x-y)$ as $\frac{\cos(x-y)}{\sin(x-y)}$ and solved for $\sin(x-y)$ and got $1,$ then thought that if $\sin(x-y)$ is $1$, so $\cos(x-y)$ must also produce that same value, because if the arguments of the trig functions which we get after doing the division $x-y$ in the fraction $\frac{\cos(x-y)}{\sin(x-y)}$ are distinct, the fraction can't be brought into the notation $\cot(x-y).$ However, I also doubt this opinion. If this my standpoint is errorful, I would like the answerers to show why.

Comment: if $\sin(\theta) = 1$, then $\cos(\theta) = 0$. I'm not sure why you said they must be the same value

Comment: $\sin (x-y)$ will not be 1. Also how do you get to conclusion that $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ should have same value?

Comment: @Brenton Oh, now I see my mistake.

Comment: @PrinceKumar "tilper" has answered your question instead of me plainly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sin(x-y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)-\cos(x)\sin(y)=-1$$

And whenever $\sin \theta = -1$, we have $\cos \theta = 0$

Comment: Can we call a solution a "hint"?

Comment: @PrinceKumar Ok, I've remove the HINT as you wish.

Comment: My point was that you could have just pointed him in the right direction rather than providing complete solution. Cheers! :)

Comment: @PrinceKumar Ah.. I thought that OP already knows how to calculate $\sin(x-y)$, but he happened to mess up with the signs, and thus I pointed that in my first line. And then I give him the direction to think why if $\sin \theta = -1$, then $\cos \theta = 0$

Answer (score 1):

> because if the arguments which we get after doing the division $x-y$ of trig functions in the fraction $\frac{\cos(x-y)}{\sin(x-y)}$ are distinct, the fraction can't be brought into the notation $\cot(x-y).$

This is true, because you're basically saying $\dfrac{\cos(x-y)}{\sin(x-y)} = \cot(x-y)$ only works because we have $x-y$ in both cosine and sine.

However, this does **not** mean that $\sin(x-y) = \cos(x-y)$.  So $\cos(x-y)$ is not necessarily equal to $1$ just because $\sin(x-y) = 1$.  (Note also that $\sin(x-y) \ne 1$ here.)

You started on the right path.  Rewrite in terms of sine and cosine.  Now use the fact that $\sin(x-y) = \sin x \cos y - \cos x \sin y$.  Get a value for $\sin(x-y)$, use that combined with the unit circle to get a value for $\cos(x-y)$.